# TypeError: must be str, not int (basic user)

Tags: python, input

I'm new to Python and just learning the basics. Can you please correct this for me and tell me how and why I was wrong?

```
age = input('Please enter your age:')
ten = 10
agePlusTen= age + ten
print('You will be', agePlusTen, 'in 10 years'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python/6.2 fixed.py", line 3, in <module>
    print('You will be', age + ten, 'in 10 years')
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. Apply `int` to it before doing math

Comment: This is a mega dupe but I can't think of the similar question atm.

Comment: Why you make 10 a var like that ?

Comment: I'm also a newbie so i wouldn't understand the answers of other 'advanced' posts.

Comment: I'm just working with variables and trying out random stuff but i will be simplifying.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was going to say that about making ten a variable, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, [**input()**](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_input.php) returns string. So, you should cast the `age` to `int` first and then add it to the variable `ten`.

The following should work.

```
age = input('Please enter your age:')
ten = 10
agePlusTen= int(age) + ten
print('You will be ' + str(agePlusTen) + ' in 10 years')
```

Also, when you want to print a string by concatenating a group of strings, don't forget to convert them to string using `str()` function if any of them is not string.

Comment: Here some more [juicy docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input)

Answer (score 0):

In python when using it always returns a string. That is when using **input()** to store variables ,the variables will be always of type string, thus to convert **age** variable into integer write as shown below :
   `age = input('Please enter your age:')
 ten = 10
 agePlusTen= int(age) + ten
 print('You will be', agePlusTen, 'in 10 years'),`

i think this should work.